# When I run this, there is a something wrong in the sum+=n statement, I don't know how to fix it

Tags: ruby

```
class Test
  def multiples
    (1..1000).each do |n|
      if n % 3 == 0 || n % 5 == 0
        sum += n
      end
      puts "The sum of multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000 is #{sum}"
    end
  end
end
test = Test.new
test.multiples
```

Error:

```
test.rb:9:in `block in multiples': undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
The sum of multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000 is 
    from test.rb:7:in `each'
    from test.rb:7:in `multiples'
    from test.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not initialised sum, adding sum = 0 should fix this:

```
class Test
  def multiples
    sum = 0
    (1..1000).each do |n|
      if n % 3 == 0 || n % 5 == 0
        sum += n
      end
      puts "The sum of multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000 is #{sum}"
    end
  end
end
test = Test.new
test.multiples
```

Comment: @Marc if Yule's answer solved your problem and you're happy with that, please upvote and accept the answer, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I remember when I started out in Ruby, I didn't really observe the error messages much, but you might find value in learning how to read those messages. You have:

```
test.rb:9:in `block in multiples': undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Just to dissect the obvious a little here. You get the following parts:

1. test.rb - Your file name
2. 9 - The line number where things break down.
3. block in multiples - There's a block with an issue
   inside 'multiples'
4. undefined method '+' - Remember that a + sign
   is actually just a method name in Ruby and different methods are
   available for different variable types. This is saying there's no
   method by the name of + for the variable type you're calling it on.
5. nil - This is the variable type you just tried to call the +
   method on.

By element 5 of that error message, you should be thinking "Why is `sum` currently `nil`?" And then look around your code and realize you've never declared it. Ruby doesn't know how to add something to `nil`, so you should immediately think about instantiating/declaring the variable 'sum' somewhere outside of the loop that it's adding things to itself.

Hopefully understanding error messages and why you had an error helps. Because if you don't understand and think through an error message, you're going to hit a road block again. It will probably be around the same time you try to create an array by shoveling something into it, instead of instantiating it first, and wonder why you get a similar error message.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks~ I guess I didn't really understand how things work in Ruby. Thanks for mentioning that + is a method, didn't notice that before.

Comment: This is a brilliant answer